# "Copy link location" keyboard shortcut in Windows 10?

Tags: firefox, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

Went through some old shortcuts I found in Google like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> but these didn't work... <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while on the link with the mouse also didn't work.

Any shortcut works for you in Win 10?

Comment: Where are you trying to copy the link locations from? Which browser?

Comment: Mozilla Firefox... :)

Comment: I don't think there is one. [Firefox Shortcuts](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Firefox.html)

Comment: I use chrome, right click on link and select "copy link address" or "save link as" faster than a keyboard.

Comment: @Moab on Firefox there's also a "copy link location" menu item on right click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Copy Link Address](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-link-address/kdejdkdjdoabfihpcjmgjebcpfbhepmh) Chrome extension for that job. You should check *Allow access to file URLs* in the settings then restart the browser

Then use [this AutoHotkey script](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/90851-i-want-single-keys-for-copy-and-paste/) to do the rest.

Answer (score 10):

Right-click + <kbd>E</kbd> works within Chrome to "copy link address."

Comment: May I ask where did you find this information?

Comment: I was searching for this for long! Thanks a thousand.

Comment: the question is tagged with [tag:firefox], **not** Chrome

Comment: @mchid just look at the [underlined accelerator key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/437975/995714) in the menu. Modern Windows may hide that by default if you initiated the command with mouse so you may need to [change the setting to always show it](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-and-use-alt-underline-keyboard-shortcut-windows-10)

Comment: @phuclv Thanks, however, the option to underline accelerator keys is a Windows option outside of Chrome which doesn't exist on a Chromebook or other OS like Ubuntu etc.

Comment: @phuclv However, [I compiled a list of accelerator keys for Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/a/1303073/167115) if anyone else is interested.

Comment: @mchid I guess that's the limitation of the DE: https://askubuntu.com/q/1271716/253474

Answer (score 3):

You can simply **drag and drop** the link to almost anywhere you want like MS Word, Notepad++ or the address bar. No need to copy it first then switch to the target application and paste

See screenshot for an easier understanding

[image: Link drag and drop]

It also works for *any selected text*, including texts on the address bar or in a textbox

[How to disable drag&drop of links by default?](https://superuser.com/q/1276123/241386)

Answer (score 1):

If it's the desktop your looking to copy to, I just drag the icon before the url to the lower right corner of screen, and when everything minimalizes, drag it to the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

or maybe <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will work... read here https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Keyboard+shortcuts

Comment: Sadly none worked :\

Comment: I don't have any ideas. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

The *Copy Link Address* extension mentioned in another answer has not been updated in a while and was causing problems with some web pages (e.g., DuckDuckGo) on my machine.

So I replaced it with a very simple macro that does the following:

- Performs a right-click at the current mouse cursor location
- Types the keystroke "A"

Since I'm a Mac user, I used Keyboard Maestro to implement this macro, but you should be able to create it with pretty much any other scripting software (e.g., AutoHotkey on Windows), too. I did verify that "Right-Click->A" also  works in Firefox on Windows to invoke *Copy Link Location*.

You can also adapt this macro very easily for other browsers, like Vivaldi, which is my main browser. For Vivaldi, I basically use the same macro, except after the right-click it types "Cop" and then hits Return.

After struggling with the *Copy Link Address* extension for some time, I finally realized that this is a problem that is trivially easy to fix with automation. Hopefully, this post will help others to come to this realization sooner than I did.

Answer (score 0):

If the link is in focus then you can simply press <kbd>≣ Menu</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> with [menu key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) being the key on the right to activate the context menu. Alternatively <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> also activates the context menu, then <kbd>L</kbd> will select *Copy Link*

If you prefer to use both mouse and keyboard like [this top-voted solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1024583/copy-link-location-keyboard-shortcut-in-windows-10/1656419#btnFollowPost-1603236) then in Firefox just use <kbd>Right-click</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Notice the underline below L in *Copy Link*. If it's different in some other languages or in another Firefox version then just replace L with the corresponding character in your case

[image: Firefox Copy Link shortcut]

Comment: This is broken behavior and should be reported to Bugzilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/. L is not a usable hotkey. The proper hotkey is A, or a key in the hotkey area, but no one can use L the way that a hotkey is intended to be used (if you are to call it a hotkey). So I do not accept this as a valid change. I assert that it is broken behavior.

Comment: @felwithe who said that L is not a usable hotkey? And why is it A? The top-voted answer is `right click + E` although it's is even more wrong, that's why I wrote this

Comment: @felwithe if you think the behavior is a bug then go file a report yourself. This answer works correctly in current Firefox versions and has nothing wrong in it

Comment: Who said `L` _is_ a useable hotkey? It isn't. You cannot show that it is, because it isn't. I can show that it isn't by the fact that no one can reach it without looking down. No testing was done. No one was consulted. Some individual or small group of people literally said "DUH I THINK L FOR "LINK" MAKES MORE SENSE" and broke a major browser for 200 million people. It's broken behavior that they cannot explain. Their only response is to close all threads talking about it. It is not a response. Firefox's hotkey for Copy Link is **broken**. The L key is not usable as a hotkey.

Comment: @felwithe **it works perfectly fine on any links on my Firefox**. Right click+L then Ctrl+V and the link will be pasted. There's nothing wrong with it. You don't even know what a hot key is. That underline is called an **accelerator key** and not hotkey

Comment: It does **not** work. It cannot be reached without looking down, reaching across the keyboard, then resetting my hand and then resetting my eyes on the screen. It is such an inconvenient process that it defeats the purpose of a hotkey. It was **never tested**. I can show what is wrong by simply having anyone use a valid hotkey 10 times, then attempting to use L 10 times. Valid hotkeys for a common function like Copy Link are in the hotkey area, like they are for every major browser including Firefox until the broken version 88.

Comment: @felwithe No, no one needs to look down just to press L if they're familiar with the keyboard. `Right click+E` is completely off-topic (not for Firefox), far worse than this and yet people liked it. And did you even read my answer? **I gave a proper hot key to copy link: `≣ Menu+L`**. How can you copy a link without knowing which link? You must give focus to it somehow by right click or tab

Comment: No one can reach the L key with their left hand without looking down. If you claim to be some superuser who can, I frankly doubt your veracity, but everyone else cannot, and I can prove that by simply having anyone do the experiment of _trying it 10 times_ for a proper hotkey on the left, and the unusable L on the right. It it broken. No one can even explain why it should be L instead of a working hotkey like A or C. It was apparently broken on a whim by a single person or small group of people, who will not allow anyone to even give feedback on it.

Comment: @felwithe `≣ Menu+L` can be reached without any look at the keyboard. And this is not a place to rant about a feature that you think is a bug

Comment: It cannot, and repeating that it can won't make it true. I gave you a simple experiment to show that it can't. You are presenting non-scientific statements to justify defending Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like different people have different interpretations of this question. In my case, I wanted to use the "Copy Link" function in Firefox (normally accessed by right-click on the link then click on "Copy Link") but do it using only the keyboard.

Solution on **Firefox 92**: <kbd>'</kbd>, (type some text to find the link), <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>

Explanations of [Firefox keyboard shortcuts](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly) used:

<kbd>'</kbd> (apostrophe) - quick search for links only
<kbd>Esc</kbd> - close the quick find bar (which leaves the link selected)
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> - toggle context menu (like right-click)
<kbd>L</kbd> - the key for "Copy **L**ink" within the context menu

Similar solution on **Chrome 92**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, (type some text to find the link), <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>