# How to disable drag&drop of links by default?

Tags: firefox, browser, drag-and-drop, about-config

I would like to disable the default behavior of Firefox which causes links to be drag&drop elements because it prevents selecting part of the text with the mouse in order to copy it. I never drag&dropped a link on purpose, the feature just causes plain frustration for me. 
There doesn't seem to be a setting for this in about:preferences.
And I also already looked into about:config, but I was not able to find what I was looking for.

So is there a way to change the default behavior without browser extensions?

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to select text from within a hyperlink on a page and Firefox is trying to drag the link instead, you can override this by holding down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key before beginning your selection.

Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to permanently prevent it from dragging the links (the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key temporarily disables clicking links, which you obviously wouldn't want to be permanent).

**Note:** This is for the Windows version of Firefox.  For Linux, you have to hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> before selecting.  I'm not sure what you would do for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent that a click into the address bar select the whole string automatically, enter `about:config` into the firefox location bar and search for the preference named `browser.urlbar.clickSelectsAll`.
Double-click and change that entry to `false`.